# SQL: Dedupe table data and manipulate merged data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL table with:

```
Id INT, Name NVARCHAR(MAX), OldName NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

There are multiple duplicates in the name column.

I would like to remove these duplicates keeping only one master copy of 'Name'. When the the dedupe happens I want to concatenate the old names into the OldName field.

E.G:

```
Dave | Steve
Dave | Will
```

Would become

```
Dave | Steve, Will
```

After merging.

I know how to de-dupe data using something like:

```
    with x as   (select  *,rn = row_number()
            over(PARTITION BY OrderNo,item  order by OrderNo)
            from    #temp1)

select * from x
where rn > 1
```

But not sure how to update the new 'master' record whilst I am at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really too complicated to do in a single update, because you need to update and delete rows.

```
select n.name,
       stuff((select ',' + t2.oldname
              from sqltable t2
              where t2.name = n.name
              for xml path (''), type
             ).value('/', 'nvarchar(max)'
                    ), 1, 1, '') as oldnames
into _temp
from (select distinct name from sqltable) n;

truncate table sqltable;

insert into sqltable(name, oldnames)
    select name, oldnames
    from _temp;
```

Of course, test, test, test before deleting the old table (copy it for safe keeping).  This doesn't use a temporary table.  That way, if something happens -- like a server reboot -- before the `insert` is finished, you still have all the data.

Your question doesn't specify what to do with the `id` column.  You can add `min(id)` or `max(id)` to the `_temp` if you want to use one of those values.

Comment: This looks good. However I am getting "Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
The value function requires 2 argument(s)." Its asking for the XQuery?

Comment: Changed the .value to .value('/','nvarchar(max)') and worked. Thanks!